# Jenkins Pipeline replaceAll and Deploy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I’m pretty new to Jenkins and was hoping to get some help.  I built a pipeline script that calls a file from a git repo, reads the file, and prints the file contents, then replacesAll “text1” with “${text2}” which I parameterized. The console output reflects the changes.

For the bat commands, I map the server and want to be able to deploy the updated file contents to a Windows server.  But what is happening it deploys the original file to the server instead of the updated file.  How can I go about getting the updated file to deploy? Thanks.

```
stage(’name’)       
     node("commercial-windows-agents")
     {
       git([url: ‘git url’, branch: 'master'])
       echo “${text2}”
       String filePath = "${Workspace}"
       println filePath
       def fileContents = readFile("${Workspace}\\filename”)
       println fileContents
       println fileContents.replaceAll(“text1”, “${text2}”)

       bat('''
       (
       net use T: \\\\server\\c$ %Password% /user:%Username%
       xcopy "%WORKSPACE%\\filename” “T:\\filepath\\” /e /y
       )
       net use T: /d /y
       ''')
     }
```

Comment: `replaceAll` returns a modified string. You need to assign that string to a variable, write that out to a file (or do both together), and then use that new file instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Try the AntBuilder():

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
def file = new File($Workspace, "filename")
ant.replace(file: file, token: “text1”, value: “${text2}”)
```